# When converting a list to an array, is it better to use np.array() or np.asarray()

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say that I already have a list that I created and assigned to a variable.

```
example = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then later on in my code I want to convert this to an array. Which of these is better practice?

```
example = np.array(example)
#or
example = np.asarray(example)
```

Or is there another way that's even better?

Comment: `asarray` calls the `array` constructor anyways, but `asarray` will not copy by default unless it has to.

Comment: Use the obvious, `np.array`.  In a general purpose function that should accept an an array as well as a list, then `asarray` may save a smidgen of time.

Comment: @user3483203 I already read that thread and I know the difference, but when I'm converting a predefined list to an array and I won't need the old list anymore, is it better to create the copy using .array() or is it better to use .asarray()?